# How to calculate TN (true negatives) in mask rcnn?

Tags: object-detection, roc

I'm trying to use mask-rcnn architecture for a binary object detection task. I wanted to generate ROC curve for performance measurement but I can't find out how I should calculate TN (true negatives). The model generates mask after further analyzing ROIs extracted from first stage. I think the number of true negatives depends on size of extracted ROIs and is not a meaningful number here where there is only background or object. So how is ROC curve generated in this situation? I studied [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-22437-z) article where ROC curve is reported so obviously I'm missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mask R-CNN tries to improve upon faster R-CNN by adding the segmentation ability and detecting the exact boundaries of the objects. The article you mentioned, uses Faster R-CNN which is an object detection method and it works with bounding boxes. When a generated bounding box doesn't contain any object and the algorithm classifies it as background, it is considered as a TN (true negative). However, in segmentation, specially for medical images, they usually use other measures for comparisons (e.g. [dice score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) and IoU). For example, if you look at [this article](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-95933-7_4), you can see the accuracy is calculated based on the dice coefficient, which is more appropriate for segmentation tasks. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195006/is-the-dice-coefficient-the-same-as-accuracy/195037#195037) explains it more completely.